# Not able to build the project

Tags: angular7

I have installed node.js ver. 12.9.0. Npm ver. 6.11.2 and angular ver 8.3.0.

Now I have created sample project by cmd `ng new SampleApp`. It gives me below warning as:

> (node:44304) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

After creating SampleApp project, I am trying to build this project using `ng serve --o`, but it gives me below error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

just Go Back To `v12.8.1` this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

> An unhandled exception occurred: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200

For me, the solution was to quit Docker Desktop